# Complex Fourier series transformation

Tags: fourier-transform

[image: Image of the steps]

In this complex Fourier transform how is the i factored to the top of the fraction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $1/i$ equal to $-i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277038/why-is-1-i-equal-to-i)

Comment: Yes it does thank you